# What is happening here? Looping by line and looping by indice

Tags: python

I am attempting to take an array of strings and transform it into an array of separate words (with the same number of columns). But the two loops are giving me very different results, and this means I can't access any of the values in the array, really.

```
array1 = [
    ["yes is a good thing","no is a bad thing"],
    ["maybe is a good","certainly is a bad"]
]

w2, h2 = 2,15;
array2 = [[0 for x in range(w2)] for y in range(h2)]

for column in range(len(array1[0])): 
    for row in range(len(array1)):
        array2[1:][column] += str(array1[row][column]).split()

for line in array2: #LOOP 1
    print(line)

for column in range(len(array2[0])): #LOOP 2
    for row in range(len(array2)):
        print(array2[row][column])
```

The results:

Loop 1 (This is what I'd like to be represented in the second loop)

```
[0, 0]
[0, 0, 'yes', 'is', 'a', 'good', 'thing', 'maybe', 'is', 'a', 'good']
[0, 0, 'no', 'is', 'a', 'bad', 'thing', 'certainly', 'is', 'a', 'bad']
[0, 0]
[0, 0]
[0, 0]
[0, 0]
[0, 0]
[0, 0]
[0, 0]
[0, 0]
[0, 0]
[0, 0]
[0, 0]
[0, 0]
```

Loop 2:

```
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
```

Basically I want an array with two columns, and then the relevant separate words going down each column. Expected output:

```
yes        no
is         is
a           a
good       bad
thing      thing
maybe      certainly
is           is
a            a
good         bad
```

Comment: Can you add the *expected* output to your question please?

Comment: You have, in total, 18 words. But you create a list of 2 x 15 numbers, and wanted to put the words in those? Are you just trying to *transpose* lists of strings?

Comment: 2nd loop produce only zeros because `len(array2[0])==2` ie number of element in *first* subarray. And slice `0:2` of any array contains only zeros. Also example of expected output for both loop and task altogether would be helpful

Comment: thanks - I have edited the original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can produce your output directly from the columns:

```
array1 = [
    ["yes is a good thing", "no is a bad thing"],
    ["maybe is a good", "certainly is a bad"]
]

words = [[word for line in col for word in line.split()] for col in zip(*array1)]
transposed = list(zip(*words))
```

`zip(*iterable)` *transposes* a matrix, moving columns to rows and vice versa.

Demo:

```
>>> array1 = [
...     ["yes is a good thing", "no is a bad thing"],
...     ["maybe is a good", "certainly is a bad"]
... ]
>>> words = [[word for line in col for word in line.split()] for col in zip(*array1)]
>>> transposed = list(zip(*words))
>>> for row in transposed:
...     print('{:8} {:8}'.format(*row))
...
yes      no
is       is
a        a
good     bad
thing    thing
maybe    certainly
is       is
a        a
good     bad
```